# my prevention to stop people muting someone twice doesnt work

Tags: discord, discord.js

when i try to unmute someone is allready muted i still get that user is muted even though i have this code.if anyone could help it would very helpfull thank you>

**if(user.roles.cache.has(muterole)) {
return message.channel.send("Given User do not have mute role so what i am suppose to take")
}**

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'unmute',
    description: "This unmutes a member",
    execute(message, args, Discord){


if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "Sorry but you do not have permission to unmute anyone"
    );
  }

  if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
    return message.channel.send("I do not have permission to manage roles.");
  }
  const user = message.mentions.members.first();

  if (!user) {
    return message.channel.send(
      "Please mention the member to who you want to unmute"
    );
 } 

 let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Muted")
 let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Verified")


 if(user.roles.cache.has(muterole)) {
  return message.channel.send("Given User do not have mute role so what i am suppose to take")
}

    user.roles.remove(muterole)
    user.roles.add(mainrole)
    message.channel.send(`**${message.mentions.users.first().username}** is unmuted`)
    
 
    user.send(`You are now unmuted from **${message.guild.name}**`)



    const MuteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#1ABC9C')
  .setDescription(`${message.mentions.users.first().username} has now been unmuted `)
  .addField('Moderator',`<@${message.author.id}>`)
  .addField('member',`${message.mentions.users.first().username}`)
  .setFooter(message.member.displayName,  message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
  .setTimestamp()
    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'logs' );channel.send(MuteEmbed)
   



    



}

}
```

Comment: Try `.has(muterole.id)`

Comment: same thing as before